# mongodb http interface authentication

Tags: mongodb, http, authentication, interface

I have a little problem with mongodb: when I connect to the http interface I have no problems, but if I try to connect after enabling authentication the browser ask me for username and password.
So far it's correct, but if I try to log in with the users I have created (one root on admin db, one userAdminAnyDatabase on admin and one dbOwner on my personal db) neither of them allows me to access! Does anyone know why? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'll start with the usual caveat that you should not use the HTTP interface on any production system, ever - turn it off for prod.  With that said, are you using MongoDB 3.0 (and in particular SCRAM SHA-1 credentials)?

The [HTTP interface](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/security-interface/#http-status-interface) does not support that auth method, per the page linked:

> Neither the HTTP status interface nor the REST API support the
>   SCRAM-SHA-1 challenge-response user authentication mechanism
>   introduced in version 3.0.

Hence, to use auth with the interface you will have to make sure you are using 2.6 or at least [2.6 style credentials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/3.0-scram/#continue-to-use-mongodb-cr).